# How do get name of max? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, max

I have query:

```
select max(sumValues) 
FROM (select dep.name AS sumName, sum(em.salary) AS sumValues 
from EMPLOYEE em 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT dep ON em.department_id=dep.id 
group by dep.id) a
```

In result I have:

```
|max numeric|
 -----------
   200
```

But I want get in result name (dep.name) of max (max(sumValues)), How can I to do it?

Comment: You want the department name of the department with the greatest sum of salaries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to sort and take the first tuple:

```
select sumName, sumValues
FROM (
    select dep.name AS sumName, sum(em.salary) AS sumValues 
    from EMPLOYEE em 
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT dep ON em.department_id=dep.id 
    group by dep.id
) a
ORDER BY sumValues DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Otherwise you can use the `HAVING` clause and a subquery over a CTE term.

(`LIMIT` is a PostgreSQL extension)

Comment: How can I do it without command 'LIMIT'? I need example, please.

Comment: Why? Using `LIMIT` is way simpler and more efficient. What problem are you attempting to solve that means you cannot use `LIMIT`?